# How to get unique records based on 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I have doubt in sql server

```
Table : emp 

    Id  |  Desc
    1   |  abc
    2   |  def
    3   | har
```

table2  : emp1

```
Id | Desc
3  | Har
4  | jai
4  | jai
5  | uou
6  | uni
6  | udkey
2  | Jainiu
```

based on above table I want output like below

```
 ID   | Desc
 1    | abc
 2    | def
 3    | har
 4    | jai
 5    | uou
 6    | uni
```

I tried like below

```
select  id, desc from emp
 union 
 select * from (select *,row_number()over(partition by id)as rn from emp1)
where rn=1
```

after executing this query I got an error like below

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

It's saying above 1st query are 2 column and 2 query are 3 column, this process
how we avoid this rn column.
please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: why `select  id ,desc from emp  union select  id ,desc from emp1` ?? error because, there is a new column rn in `emp1` table.

Comment: There's also no `ORDER BY` in `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @srinivas see the below output will exactly match the output you want

Comment: When you use UNION the number of column and column type must be same

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT id, 
       desc 
FROM   emp 
UNION 
SELECT id, 
       desc 
FROM   emp1
```

`Union` will automatically do a `distinct` and `sort` it in the proper order, you don't need to do anything, no windwos functions required

Result:

```
 ID   | Desc
 1    | abc
 2    | def
 2    | Jainiu
 3    | har
 4    | jai
 5    | uou
 6    | uni
 6    | udkey
```

If you want to remove `udkey` and `Jainiu` please mention a logi to choose between `def` and `Jainiu` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

using the Union or Distinct we can reomve duplicates and row_number we can get output and In union should have equal number of columns 
    DECLARE @emp  TABLE 
        ([Id] int, [Desc] varchar(3))
    ;

```
INSERT INTO @emp
    ([Id], [Desc])
VALUES
    (1, 'abc'),
    (2, 'def'),
    (3, 'har')


DECLARE @emp1  TABLE 

    ([Id] int, [Desc] varchar(6))


INSERT INTO @emp1
    ([Id], [Desc])
VALUES
    (3, 'Har'),
    (4, 'jai'),
    (4, 'jai'),
    (5, 'uou'),
    (6, 'uni'),
    (6, 'udkey'),
    (2, 'Jainiu')


    ;with CTE AS (

      select 
id,
[Desc],
Row_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,[Desc]DESC)RN 
         from 

      (select distinct id,[Desc] from @EMP
    UNION ALL 
    select distinct id,[Desc] from @EMP1)T)

    select id,[Desc] from CTE 
    WHERE RN = 1
```